# Can I create 2 or more objects in main()

Tags: java

I set a singleton pattern class (e.g. Singleton) by following the instruction and create a demo class (e.g. SingletonDemo) , in demo class I try to create 2 instance of Singleton in main() by below code:

```
Singleton instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();
Singleton instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();
```

I thought error would have popped up when instance2 was created, but instance2 was created successfully, why? I think only single instance should be created for Single Pattern

Comment: `Singleton.getInstance()` normally wouldn't be "creating" an instance. It's "getting" a reference to the single instance. In other words, `instance1` and `instance2` are variables to the one and same object. If you're in doubt, post your `getInstance()` method.

Comment: In a Singleton pattern, the `getInstance()` method is supposed to ensure that a single object reference is sent every time. So even though you have two variables here, they refer to the same object. And even if it was wrongly implemented, I don't think Java throws any errors.

Comment: Singleton.getInstance() return the same object reference no matter how many time you invoke at any method. in your case both instance1 and instance2 both are pointing to the same object on JVM heap

Comment: There's no "error" because (if implemented correctly) `getInstance` will return the singleton instance. You're not (directly) creating the instance; the singleton instance is managed by `Singleton`, however it does its thing. If you want to signal an error then `getInstance` would have to maintain a call count or something, but that seems really awful, since the point of a singleton is to let any callers retrieve the singleton instance, which could happen anywhere, anytime.

Comment: Also your question title seems different than your actual question.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of singletons is that there can only be one instance of that class at a time. It always returns the same object. It's not possible to have two objects of the same singleton, atleast without modifying the class itseld but that might break something and it isn't even possible if it's a part of JDK.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a Singleton is that the first call to `getInstance()` creates and returns the (single) instance, and all future (happens-after) calls to `getInstance()` return ***the same instance***.

This behavior allows any module that needs a reference to the singleton to retrieve it without having to worry about whether it needs to create it.  By definition, a second call to `getInstance()` should NOT throw an error.